# Use after_stat or stat_* in ggplot2 for doing operations on aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Often I do a lot of operations on a df with *tidyverse* and next, I want to plot that but in some ggplot's functions, I still have to do operations on df.

I've done an example to do that clearer. My objective is don't call in `scale_fill_brewer()` the df but something like `after_stat()`:

```r
USArrests %>% 
  mutate(Arrest = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("State") %>%
  tibble() %>% 
  mutate(State = reorder(State, Arrest)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Arrest, y = State, fill = Arrest)) + 
  geom_col() +
  # scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#04e762", mid = "#f5b700", high = "#dc0073", midpoint = after_stat(mean(Arrest))) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#04e762", mid = "#f5b700", high = "#dc0073", midpoint = mean(rowSums(USArrests))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

I would like to do something like that: `scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#04e762", mid = "#f5b700", high = "#dc0073", midpoint = after_stat(mean(..fill..)))`. Is it possible? I hope to be clear. In this example, it's not very hard but in other cases, I have to pass a lot of functions to an argument before getting what I want.

EDIT:

In this case, is more relevant the problem:
in `midpoint = mean(.$score)` I have to call df newly

```r
set.seed(1)
tibble(score = round(runif(100, 1, 10))) %>%
  count(score) %>%
  tibble() %>%
  {
    ggplot(., aes(x = score, y = n, fill = score)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
      scale_fill_gradient2(
        low = "#EE602D",
        mid =  "#FFCF26",
        high = "#01AEE6",
        midpoint = mean(.$score)
      ) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what `after_stat` is made for. As the docs (`?after_stat`) make clear, `after_stat` (or `after_scale` or `stage`) can (only) be used inside the `aes()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you misunderstood what `after_stat` is made for. As the docs (`?after_stat`) make clear, `after_stat` (or `after_scale` or `stage`)

> can *(only)* be used inside the `aes()` function used as the `mapping` argument in layers.

Hence, `after_stat` can only be used in `geom_xxx` or `stat_xxx` layers.

If your goal is to do the data wrangling and the plotting in one pipeline and want to use variables in other layers, then in case of the `magrittr` pipe `%>%` one option would be to wrap your `ggplot` code in `{}` which allows to pass the dataset to multiple `ggplot` layers, e.g. you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tibble)

USArrests %>%
  mutate(Arrest = rowSums(.)) %>%
  rownames_to_column("State") %>%
  tibble() %>%
  mutate(State = reorder(State, Arrest)) %>%
  {
    ggplot(., aes(x = Arrest, y = State, fill = Arrest)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_gradient2(
        low = "#04e762", mid = "#f5b700", high = "#dc0073",
        midpoint = mean(.$Arrest)
      ) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I've modified the question so now it's more clear the problem